# SO Meta icon in close-vote menu should be more visible

Tags: feature-request, dark-mode, close-dialog

When you go to close a question as "Belongs on `<site-Meta>`" on SO in Dark Mode, the Meta icon shows up a bit gray (slightly invisible):

[image]

Can we please have something that pops out a bit more, like this:

[image]

Comment: I think this is a bug. It should be more visible according to the dark mode rules.

Comment: For comparison: this is how the MSO icon looks like in the [site switcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0M8s.png). Its source comes from `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/favicons-sprite16-dark.png`.